# Smallest Power of 2 greater than n

Tags: c++, algorithm

This is slightly different than all the other questions asking just for an algorithm. I would like to know whether there is an O(1) algorithm that does this *in C++*. It seems that since C++ is such a low-level language that works closely with bits, there would be a quick O(1) function that would return the highest bit, to which we could just do `<< 1` to get the answer.

Comment: You might want to qualify your expectations for O(1). O(1) does not mean "one operation", but "has a maximum runtime regardless of input size". This is why, say, division, which takes multiple CPU cycles, is still considered O(1). Because C++ integers are bounded, even a naive "traverse the bits" algorithm is O(1).

Comment: There's a lot of discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/671815/207421) about a computation for the highest set bit, and some links as well.

Comment: duplicates: [Algorithm for finding the smallest power of two that's greater or equal to a given value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/364985/995714), [Algorithm for finding the smallest power of two that's greater or equal to a given value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/364985/995714), [Rounding up to next power of 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/466204/995714)

Comment: other duplicates: [What is the fastest/most efficient way to find the highest set bit (msb) in an integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/671815/995714), [how to know the position of the first(left -> right) '1' bit in a char efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23083504/995714), [Find the highest order bit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53161/995714)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way in C++20 is [`std::bit_ceil(n)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_ceil)

In older C++ standard use [`boost::multiprecision::msb()`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/gen_int.html) or compiler intrinsics of your compiler like [`__builtin_clz()`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) or [`_BitScanReverse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/bitscanreverse-bitscanreverse64?view=msvc-160)... to get the most significant bit and then return that value

```
return 1 << boost::multiprecision::msb(n);           // cross-platform
return n == 0 ? 1 : 1 << (31 - __builtin_clz(n));    // GCC, Clang
int index;
return _BitScanReverse(&index, n)) ? 1 << index : 1; // MSVC, ICC
return n == 0 ? 1 : 1 << (31 - _lzcnt_u32(n));       // ICC
```

(Assuming you want to get the smallest power of 2 greater than `n` which is an `int` and contains 32 bits)

Comment: Thank you. It turns out that for ints, it is relatively simple: `(1 << (32 - __builtin_clz(n)))`

Answer (score 2):

Sure.

```
uint32_t smallest_power_of_two_greater_than_n(int n) {
  std::array<uint32_t, 32> powers_of_two = {0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192, 16384, 32768, 65536, 131072, 262144, 524288, 1048576, 2097152, 4194304, 8388608, 16777216, 33554432, 67108864, 134217728, 268435456, 536870912, 1073741824, 2147483648};
  for (uint32_t minimum : powers_of_two) {
    if (n <= minimum)
      return minimum;
  // If there's no representable number... return 0?
  return 0;
}
```

This is `O(32)` which is the same as `O(1)`.

Comment: Who said that *n* is on 32 bits?

Comment: @Breakingnotsobad It doesn't matter. It could be 8 or 128, it is still *O(k)*, which is still *O(1)*.

Comment: So, it is O(*b*) with *b* number of bits.

Answer (score -2):

No, because std::log has O(log log n).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
        int n;
        std::cin >> n;

        auto logtwo = std::log(n) / std::log(2); //calculate the log of n to the base of 2.
        double integer; //stores the integer part of logtwo.

        //check if the variable logtwo is an integer or not
        if(std::modf(logtwo, &integer) == 0.0)
                std::cout << logtwo;
        else
                std::cout << static_cast<int>(logtwo+1);
}
```

Reference:
*[What is the complexity of the log function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317414/what-is-the-complexity-of-the-log-function)*

Comment: You're assuming that `log()` is the only solution.

Comment: using `log` to get the most significant bit position is the most inefficient way and also has [a high possibility of returning an incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67559309/995714) due to the nature of floating-point math. Almost all architectures can get log2 of an integer in 1 or 2 instructions